# Can iptables be hacked / circumvented

Tags: firewalls, iptables

We currently have a server that blocks all connections using iptables, and we have to whitelist an IP expressly in order to be able to access the server remotely.

Essentially, the first rule allows the whitelisted IPs (including localhost interface) to progress further to the other chains on the firewall, while rejecting any IP that is not on the list.

Is it possible for an attacker to somehow circumvent the iptables rules to gain access to the server?

Sample rules follow below:

`Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1507K  136M ALLOW      all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0`

Chain ALLOW (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 183K   36M next_chain  all  --  *      *       198.###.##.###       0.0.0.0/0
3053K  237M ACCEPT      all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 116K 5859K REJECT      all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Comment: What about IPv6 traffic?

Comment: Good question. Worth noting that my answer assumes there's no IPv6 address assigned to any interface.

Comment: I'm using open suse 42ish and only set up ipv4 with yast lan. didn't even bother with ipv6. guessing that is safe enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your INPUT chain is largely useless as it forwards all packets from all interfaces to the ALLOW chain anyway - you could've just implemented the ALLOW chain rules in the INPUT chain.

With the rules you have there, UDP and ICMP traffic can be sent to the server by spoofing the source IP address. Response packets would not be received by the attacker, but this may not be necessary for certain attack types.

TCP packets (e.g. SYN) can also reach the server in the same way, but a connection cannot be created as the attacker could not construct a full TCP handshake.

Of course, the attacker would need to know which source IPs are accepted in order to spoof it.

Other than that the rules look alright.

Comment: I did a spotcheck on the server and found a foreign (otherwise blocked) that had an established session with a service. Is it possible for a service to enable access beyond the scope of iptables?

Comment: What's the probability for a source IP spoofing in the Internet? (not local/internal) Would an ISP even route that kind of packets?